# Dynamic user credential generation with Powershell for Basic Auth Implementation

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Requirement: Would like to have basic auth setup using custom php script. 
Would like to :

> - Create user credentials dynamically
> - Create the cred php file with these credentials updated
> - Update the username & password to respective for Azure WebApp settings.

[ ***Note***: FTPing the cred and auth files automatically if missing would be in upcoming post ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools & Pre-requisites :
Azure Powershell 4.0+
Windows Powershell ISE
Knowledge of Storage Account ( Name, RG's )
Knowledge of WebApp for which backup is desired ( WebApp Name and RG )
Valid & Active Azure portal / AD login credentials

***RESULT*** : *On Azure Portal, The webapp in focus would have 'global_cred' variable key set with credentials generated stored as its value in application settings section as [username:password] format.*

```
            #######################
            # Function to Generate dynamic 22char random string for password use
            # Call custom function to write php constants for basic auth 
            Function writeFocusDomainCredFile{

                param( $configObject, $hash, $farmprojectname )
                #setting auth username:password
                $configObject.authPasswordKey = (Get-RandomAlphanumericString -length 22 | Tee-Object -variable teeTime )
                $hash['global_cred'] = [String]( $configObject.authUsernameKey + ':' + $configObject.authPasswordKey )
                $prfilename = ( $configObject.ftpappdirectory + '\cred.php')
                writeProjectBasicAuthCredOnNew -filename $prfilename -configObject $configObject
            }

            ##########################
            # Function to write the credentials to cred php file for basic auth use
            # This file with other dependent files could be automatically ftp'd. 
            # Would share in another post 
            Function writeProjectBasicAuthCredOnNew{
               param( $filename
                      ,$configObject
                      )

                writeDeployFileFiltersForDomain -ReportFileName $filename
                Add-Content $filename ( "<?php" )
                Add-Content $filename ("define('WPIZED_AUTH_USER', '" + $configObject.authUsernameKey + "');"); 
                Add-Content $filename ("define('WPIZED_AUTH_PASS', '" + $configObject.authPasswordKey + "');");   
            }

            ###################################################################################################
            # Configure Below as You prefer or desire #


            $properties = @{
                            'ResourceName' = "AzureAppName";
                            'myResourceGroupName' = "{App Resource Group Name}"; 
                            'mySubscriptionName' = "{subscription name}"; 
                            'adminEmail' = "H.Bala@volunteering.com";
                            'ResourceGroupLocation' = "East US";      
                            'authUsernameKey' = 'HBalaUsername'; #For this post, using fixed username as 'HBalaUsername'
                            'authPasswordKey' = '';
                            'PathFormatDate' = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y_%m_%d";

                       }
            $configObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
            Write-Output $configObject



            #Login cmdlet for active session
            Login-AzureRmAccount
            Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription 
            (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription
            Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName 

            #Pull the Webapp details and configuration
            $webApp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $configObject.myResourceGroupName -Name $configObject.ResourceName 
            #Pull the Application Listing Environment / Configuration Variables
            $appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
            $hash = @{}
            ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) {
               $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
            }


            writeFocusDomainCredFile -configObject $configObject -hash $hash
            #[FTP Deploy Logic of this file and other basic auth or files shall cover in seperate topic ]
            #[ Only setting the generated Credentials and saving to Application setting focused here ]
            Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $configObject.myResourceGroupName -Name $configObject.ResourceName -AppSettings $hash
```

**Disclaimer**: *The intention is to share to another newbie who might find this helpful.*